# Creating .doc on Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-android-api

My goal is to programmatically create .doc on Google Drive with text and generated shapes.

My first problem that I cannot overcome is that when I create a doc file the file is generated saved on google drive but can not be opened .

Before when I created plain text files everything was OK.

```
private void createFile() {

        final Task<DriveFolder> rootFolderTask = getDriveResourceClient().getRootFolder();
        final Task<DriveContents> createContentsTask = getDriveResourceClient().createContents();
        Tasks.whenAll(rootFolderTask, createContentsTask)
                .continueWithTask(new Continuation<Void, Task<DriveFile>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Task<DriveFile> then(@NonNull Task<Void> task) throws Exception {
                        DriveFolder parent = rootFolderTask.getResult();

                        final Task<MetadataBuffer> Createlist = getDriveResourceClient().listChildren(parent);

                        DriveContents contents = createContentsTask.getResult();
                      OutputStream outputStream = contents.getOutputStream();
                    try (Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream)) {
                        writer.write("Witaj z nuclearhelperaa");
                    }
                        MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                                .setTitle("test6")
                              //  .setMimeType("text/plain")
                               .setMimeType("application/msword")
                                .setStarred(true)
                                .build();

                        return getDriveResourceClient().createFile(parent, changeSet, contents);
                    }
                })
                .addOnSuccessListener(this,
                        new OnSuccessListener<DriveFile>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(DriveFile driveFile) {
                                showMessage(getString(R.string.file_created,
                                        driveFile.getDriveId().encodeToString()));
                                finish();
                            }
                        })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create file", e);
                        showMessage(getString(R.string.file_create_error));
                        finish();
                    }
                });
        // [END create_file]
    }
```

Is my task possible? I mean after creating a doc put some images formatted text and generated shapes (I need to create very simple picture containing couple dots) is possible to fulfil and if yes do you know some good libraries to make it possible?

Comment: Seems like you're trying to create all of this programmatically. What I would suggest is to create a UI interface where you do all the editing and writing and then just create/upload the file using [Files.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create).

Comment: Thank You for Your comment , This is very good idea I will create some templates add them to my app reasources I suppose It would be the best to assets folder and then modify them and transer to Google drive , I suppose I need some open officy library for modifying.. or something like this, but to be honest ido not know rest api is it possible to manage it with normal android google drive api?